# Swift How to pause or remove specific concurrent thread? and Can I create 'grouped thread' in backgound thread?

Tags: swift, multithreading

I want to pause a thread when i click a button.

and Can I create 'grouped thread' in backgound thread? I pharse open api from web by using grouping multiple thread. and I hope this grouping thread is backgroundthread. how can i do this

Comment: Way too vague. Could you show your code? Could you define what a "grouped" thread is better? I've been in IT for 40 years and never heard that term. Threads (to me) are just that - **separate** processes that *can* be done concurrently. Maybe you can "chain" these processes, but "group" them? Please, how can we help you with so little details?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you read up on `Operation`, `OperationQueue`, `BlockOperation` etc.